# Cumulatively expand a category to include all previous observations in R

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
df = as.data.frame(structure(list(ID = c(1,2,1,2),
                              value = c(10,12,14,16),
                              category = c(1,1,2,2))))
```

And I want to make it into this cumulative dataframe for each `category`, where each row is inserted in the sequential category:

```
desired_df = as.data.frame(structure(list(ID = c(1,2,1,2,1,2),
                              value = c(10,12,10,12,14,16),
                              category = c(1,1,2,2,2,2))))
```

With the `desired_df`, I want to be able to plot the distribution of observations in each category cumulatively (each category is a time step).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can loop through the `unique` elements of 'category', get the sequence, use that to subset the original dataset, `transform` the `category` column, and `rbind` the `list` elements

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(df$category), function(i) 
         transform(df[df$category %in% seq_len(i),], category = i)))
#   ID value category
#1  1    10        1
#2  2    12        1
#3  1    10        2
#4  2    12        2
#5  1    14        2
#6  2    16        2
```

Comment: That worked, thanks, but I had to make sure category was numeric.

Comment: @ThirstforKnowledge  If it is not `numeric`, then `match(df$category, unique(df$category))` will give the numeric version, which can be looped